# pod lib lint doesn't lint

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I have a library published on Cocoapods.

When I run `pod lib lint` from the directory containing the MyProject.podspec the command line hangs on

```
$ pod lib lint 

-> MyProject
```

Yes this is the .podspec I want to lint. What should I do then?

Answer (score 0):

Add the --verbose flag:

`pod lib lint --verbose`